# Working with Eclipse .classpath and project files in Git?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, ant

My firm is moving from PVCS to Git and I would like to know how can it help with the issues..

The current process is

- We check everything out of PVCS
- We then open Eclipse and Import the files in
- We then have to fix the .classpath and profile file due to all the stuff not having jars in same place
- Lock File in PVCS
- Make Changes in Eclipse
- Copy File from Eclipse workspace to PVCS folder
- Unlock File

--- That was the current process, very long and room for error

What I would like to move everything to git and just do a git pull but I dont want the .classpath and project file issue like I have in PVCS all the time.. I am thinking can I tell git to only read the .classpath and project file and never update it?

I would love to hear how old eclipse using are working with git and ant.. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should put the `.classpath` file in `.gitignore` so that it never enters git in the first place.
This way, each developer will have a purely local copy.

To manage your dependencies, you should use Maven; its pom.xml is machine-independent and can live in git, and Eclipse can generate everything else from that file.

Comment: can we use maven and ant?

Comment: @JMSAZ2013: Yes, but you should consider using Maven to replace Ant.

Comment: the issue is that the firms ant scr is very big

Comment: I am working with a multi-module project. Adding `.classpath` and `.project` to `.gitignore` is only ignoring the instance in the root directory, but the sub-folders containing `.classpath` and `.project` are still showing up as changes. I tried adding `**/.classpath` to `.gitignore` but that does not appear to work.